# How does a not exists or exists query look like in Mongodb?

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to MongoDb and am trying to see if I can do an exists() query in Mongodb.

The collection I'm playing with has users (with details such as company and a billingGroup) and expectedCompanies.

Normally in Oracle the users and expectedCompanies would be in two tables and I would query this like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM tableUsers
    WHERE exists (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM tableExpectedCompanies 
        WHERE 
            tableExpectedCompanies.companyname != tableUsers.companyName and 
            tableExpectedCompanies.billingGroup =  tableUsers.companyName.billingGroup
        )
```

In MongoDb it's now all in one collection, roughly like this:

```
    {
          "_id" : "billingGroupX", 
          "expectedCompanies" : ["CompanyA", "company B", "supercompany X"],
          "users" : [{"name":..., "company": ...}, {}, {}]
}
```

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
db.MasterData.find(
    {'users.company': 
        {$nin: db.MasterData.find(
                {},
                {'expectedCompanies:1'})
        }
    })
```

But of course failed miserably, first error was:

```
error: { "$err" : "$nin needs an array", "code" : 13277 }
```

**Is there actually an exists or not exists analogue in MongoDb ?**

Or something like an *in* or *not in* condition?

**edit** : After initial negative feedback on my question. Please note that I'm struggling to find an exists / not exists / in / not in condition *where you can use a subquery* as it is normally done in SQL.

Comment: Did you look at the docs? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Comment: @Lix The docs point me to the $in operator (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in) but the examples are not against a subdocument

Comment: @Lix Doesn't look like a duplicate to me, the other SO link is an example to find whether a field exists, but I'm trying to find if field values exist

Comment: The docs say that those operators are related, but as with any field, you can access subdocuments using the dot syntax. [This section](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#equality-match-on-fields-within-subdocument) speaks about exact match, but changing the operator will yield the same behavior.

Comment: Saying `"field values exists"` is pretty much the same as the equality operator - you are matching against a value.

Comment: There are `$exists` and also `$in` and `$nin`. It all depends on what you are wanting to do.

Comment: After getting more info from you here in the comments I agree that the suggested duplicate is not appropriate. I've removed that suggestion.

Comment: Hey @Lix I probably should have highlighted that example Mongodb query of me a bit better. I was already using the $nin operator, but am struggling to find how to get Mongodb to evaluate the field values. Coming to think of it, I am more searching how to perform subqueries, if that's possible at all. P.s. Is that downvote from you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so here is the statement you need to understand.

> **MongoDB does not do Joins**

Even in this *sub-query* form you **cannot** include another query from another collection in your statement. That said, note the following:

> error: { "$err" : "$nin needs an array", "code" : 13277 }

So you did not supply an **array** as required, but you tried to put in a statement. Then you can consider the code:

```
var results = db.MasterData.find({}, {"expectedCompanies:1"}).toArray();
```

And looking at that by itself you will see that it is going to return the "expectedCompanies" field from **all** results. I add the `.toArray()` function at the end to show that something you **might** have been trying to do was not going to work as you would be getting a **cursor** and not an array. But that would not work here as the **array** even from this statement refers to the **whole** collection, not just from **one** document.

So what you **may** well be "trying" to do is match (or specfically **not** match) the "users.company" value to the "expectedCompanies" values. So in MongoDB you do that like this:

```js
db.MasterData.aggregate([

    // Unwind the "users" array
    { "$unwind": "$users" },

    // Unwind the "expectedCompanies" array
    { "$unwind": "$expectedCompanies" },

    // Project a match condition
    { "$project": {
        "users": 1,
        "matching": { "$eq": [
           "$users.company",
           "$expectedCompanies"
        ]}         
    }},

    // Filter the results
    { "$match": { "matching": false }},

    // Group the duplicate entries from the unwind
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "users": {
               "name": "$users.name",
               "company": "$users.company"
            }
        }
    }},

    // Project a nicer document
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "users": "$_id.users"
    }}
])
```

This uses [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) in order to [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the elements in the arrays and compare them against each other. Each array needs to be "un-wound" in separate stages. The actual comparison is done in the first [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage, using the [$eq](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) logical operator to compare the two values. Where they equal the result is `true`, where not then it is `false`.

Following that, then we use a $match stage to "filter" the results to the `false` value we want. This is just like a normal `.find()` query. Then the results are sent through [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), to bring together the keys from the "users" document. This is because when the arrays were "un-wound" each entry was "copied" for every element in the other "expectedCompanies" array. Think of that [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) form just like "de-normalizing" the data. Grouping removes the duplicates here.

Finally since everything was "grouped" under one key, then [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) is used again to re-shape the results into something more like what you want.

So the usage is a fair bit different from a *"sub-query"* form, but that is how you do the statement to **compare** the values within two arrays in your document.

Answer (score -1):

Here are different approach for the Exist() or IN() SQL function transformation. 
it's a simple javascript and useful, but for performance, you will need proper indexes.

```
var mycursor = db.tableUsers.find( {} ) 

mycursor.forEach( function (x){ 
    var o = db.tableExpectedCompanies.count( { billingGroup : x.billingGroup, companyname  : {$ne: x.companyName}   } )
    if ( o > 0) {
        //print('The _id exists! ' + x._id); //debugging only
        printjson(x) ; 
        }
} )
```

Comment: The original question concerned a MongoDB table where everything was in a single collection, not two separate tables. This does not improve the selected answer.